# How to limit the max number of parallel threads in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a program (Perl) that kicks off a huge amount of threads (each one in charge of creating graphics based on data processing).
Each thread I start using:

```
my @threads //list to store threads that have been launched

push @threads,threads->create(\mySubName,params...);
```

The threads fire off correctly but after a while, after I have opened several of them Perl interpreter crashes (I assume it is related to memory?). So my solution is to limit the number of threads I open at a time, I picked 15. And I want to add a sub before each create line to check if it is ok to fire off the next thread or perform a sleep while I wait for one to finish. This is how I tried to do it.

```
sub checkThreads{
    my $addThread = 0;
    until($addThread){
        my $totalThreads = 0;
        foreach my $task (@threads){
            if($task->is_running()){$totalThreads++;}
        }
        if($totalThreads <= 15 ){
            print "Ok to add new thread, carry on!\n";
            $addthread = 1;
        }else{
            print "Waiting for $totalThreads threads to fire next one...\n";
            sleep 2;
        }
    }
}
```

So each time I want to create a new thread I would just call

```
&checkThreads;
```

And that would take care to create a delay while I wait for some threads to clean up.
The problem is that when I call that sub, the moment I hit the line where I check:

```
$task->is_running()
```

The program exits and stops running without any error or warning. I just want a sub that counts the running threads to limit them.

How can I perform this count successfully?

Other things I have tried are evaluating the following line:

```
scalar(threads->list());
```

But that gives me a weird value, like it is an unblessed reference I believe that looks like:

```
threads=SCALAR(0x80fea8c)
```

Comment: btw, that's (stringification of a) *blessed* ref

Comment: very, very BTW - do bear in mind that threads in perl are not like threads in other programming languages - they are very resource hungry, since each thread have a COPY of all the variables. They are still useful in some cases, but in every cases where I have to do paralellization, forking works much better. It is not related directly to your question, I just wanted to tell you that. :)

Comment: What version of Perl?  What version of threads?  And are your threads detached (perhaps self-detaching in mySubName)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Thread::Semaphore](https://metacpan.org/module/Thread::Semaphore) provides a [counting semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_semaphore) to limit concurrency:

```
my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new(15); # max 15 threads
my @threads = map {
    # request a thread slot, waiting if none are available:
    $sem->down;
    threads->create(\&mySubName, @params)
} 0..100;
$_->join for @threads;
```

And in your function:

```
sub mySubName {
    do_stuff();
    # release slot:
    $sem->up;
}
```

Comment: Richard I think this is working, I implemented it in the script and looks like indeed it is controlling my max threads, is there a way I can peek at the current value that a semaphore holds? Because I ran it but after going at it for a while my script just hangs at a  `$sem->down;`

Comment: I lowered the amount of threads to 5 and it is working fine, still with 7 looks like the program stalls at some point, not sure why. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can get the currency value of the semaphore by dereferencing the object itself, which is just a blessed reference to the maximum value (default of 1) minus its counts. So to get the current number of outstanding threads, evaluate `$max - $$sem`.

Comment: Can we use a shared scalar variable to count how many threads are running? I mean at the first line of mySubName(), we increase the counter by 1 and decrease it by 1 at return.

Answer (score 1):

Looking the docs,

```
my $count = threads->list();
```

should work, contrary to what you say. What do the docs for the version of threads *you* are using say? Well, you could use the following as a workaround.

```
my $count = () = threads->list();
```

Comment: I used the semaphore approach that Richard proposed, but I tried this out and it does give the count of actual threads in the list, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
man perlthrtut

What Threads Are Running?
   "threads->list()" returns a list of thread objects, one for each thread
    that's currently running and not detached.  Handy for a number of
```

In other words, find out how many items are in the list that threads->list() returns and you have your count.

You might want to investigate [Thread::Pool](http://search.cpan.org/~elizabeth/Thread-Pool-0.33/lib/Thread/Pool.pm) or other cpan packages to see if someone else has already done the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: When I try to use threads->list(), I get the following result:    Can't locate auto/threads/lists.al in @INC (@INC contains: C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo 3.5\lib\support\dbgp\perllib C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo 3.5\lib\support\dbgp\perllib C:/Perl/lib C:/Perl/site/lib .) at C:\path\main3.pl line 508

Comment: If `threads->list()` returns a list, you can capture the length more easily than with a loop...like `$totalThreads = scalar(threads->list());`, can't you?

Comment: ok it was a typo, I had  threads->lists() instead of  threads->list(), but now I run this  
    my $totalThreads;  
    foreach my $thr (threads->list()){  
        $totalThreads++;  
    }  
    print "Threads active: " . $totalThreads . "\n";  
  
And what I get is:  
  
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) for the line where I print

Comment: @jonathan, if I use the scalar() way I get the same message: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) when I try to print the count

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, No, to capture the length of a list, u have to use a trick like the one I used. Although, `thread->list` is suppose to return the number of threads in scalar context. The OP must have an old version of threads.pm.

Comment: @gorba: Say "my $totalThreads = 0;" to get rid of the uninitialized value.  Do you have some reason to suspect you have threads active at this point?  Also, instead of looping through the threads adding to a counter you can just directly access the count since it is a list.  See ikegami's answer below if you have never seen that syntax.