# perl threading core dump

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a perl script that does a lot of processing. It is multithreaded using the example from the accepted solution from this question:

[How to limit the max number of parallel threads in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596493/how-to-limit-the-max-number-of-parallel-threads-in-perl)

As it runs it seems to begin starting and running threads correctly.. Then it throws this error and dumps the core.

perl: posixio.c:342: px_rel: Assertion `pxp->bf_offset <= offset && offset < pxp->bf_offset + (off_t) pxp->bf_extent' failed.

My question... what does that mean?? What is happening?

Comment: Do you get that error with a newer build of `perl`?

Comment: Note that the linked thread discusses a poor approach to multi-threading.

Comment: @David Schwartz I understand that there is a bug... my question is again: what does that say is happening?

Comment: @David Schwartz, In an XS module or `perl`, but not in "the script".

Comment: @ikegami noted but that doesnt help me understand the bug

Comment: It means that expression was false and it shouldn't be. If you want to find out why it was false, you'll have to backtrack. Of course, there's a good chance someone's already done it and fixed the bug, thus my earlier comment.

Comment: @ikegami ahhh.. running version 5.10.1

Comment: Yeah, that's not the newest by far. [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) can help you install different versions of Perl locally. (Don't forget `-Dusethreads`!)

Comment: @ikegami understood but I won't have the luxury of installing a new version of perl on the machine it will be running on. can you recommend a better means of multithreading?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30727/discussion-between-steve-and-ikegami)

Comment: If possible, one wants to use a worker model, where you create a fixed pool of threads and have them perform whatever tasks that you want them to do. No reason to believe your crash is related to not using a worker model.

Comment: @ikegami give me an answer to check and its yours. thanks man

Comment: [Example simple worker model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12374670/589924)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assertion error is thrown by `assert(EXPR)`, a C macro that kills the program if its argument evaluates to something false. (Though for performance reasons, `assert` is a no-op in non-debug builds.)

So that means the stated expression was false and it should never be. If you want to find out why it was false, you'll have to backtrack.

Of course, there's a good chance someone's already done it and fixed the bug, thus you should try your code with a newer version of Perl. [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) can help you install a new version of Perl locally. (Don't forget `-Dusethreads`!)