# Perl: Correctly passing array for threads to work on

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm learning how to do threading in Perl. I was going over the example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596493/how-to-limit-the-max-number-of-parallel-threads-in-perl) and adapted the solution code slightly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore;

my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new(2); # max 2 threads
my @names = ("Kaku", "Tyson", "Dawkins", "Hawking", "Goswami", "Nye");
my @threads = map {
    # request a thread slot, waiting if none are available:
    foreach my $whiz (@names) {
        $sem->down;
        threads->create(\&mySubName, $whiz);
    }
} @names;

sub mySubName {
    return "Hello Dr. " . $_[0] . "\n";
    # release slot:
    $sem->up;
}

foreach my $t (@threads) {
    my $hello = $t->join();
    print "$hello";
}
```

Of course, this is now completely broken and does not work. It results in this error:

```
C:\scripts\perl\sandbox>threaded.pl
Can't call method "join" without a package or object reference at C:\scripts\perl\sandbox\threaded.pl line 24.
Perl exited with active threads:
        0 running and unjoined
        9 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

My objective was two-fold:

- Enforce max number of threads allowed at any given time
- Provide the array of 'work' for the threads to consume

In the original solution, I noticed that the `0..100;` code seems to specify the amount of 'work' given to the threads. However, in my case where I want to supply an array of work, do I still need to supply something similar?

Any guidance and corrections very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're storing the result of `foreach` into `@threads` rather than the result of `threads->create`.

Even if you fix this, you collect completed threads too late. I'm not sure how big of a problem that is, but it might prevent more than 64 threads from being started on some systems. (64 is the max number of threads a program can have at a time on some systems.)

A better approach is to reuse your threads. This solves both of your problems and avoids the overhead of repeatedly creating threads.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 2;

sub work {
   my ($job) = @_;
   ...
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         while (my $job = $q->dequeue()) {
            work($job);
         }
      };
   }

   $q->enqueue(@names);  # Can be done over time.
   $q->end();            # When you're done adding.
   $_->join() for threads->list();
}
```

Comment: This approach definitely seems better for what I'm doing. If I want to save the data returned by `$_->join()` can I just do a foreach and push to a new array?

Comment: Also, how important is it to specify 3.01? Is that particular version the most widely used one?

Comment: If you need to send responses back, create a response queue.

Comment: 3.01 introduced `->end`

Comment: If I'm using version 2.0 of Thread::Queue, what is the equivalent of `->end`? I tried googling for 2.0 documentation, but I can only find 3.01 documentation.

Comment: You can find the documentation for 2.01 [here](https://metacpan.org/module/JDHEDDEN/Thread-Queue-2.01/lib/Thread/Queue.pm). That's really old, though (released Feb 2008.) I recommend upgrading if you can.

Comment: `$q->enqueue(undef) for 1..NUM_WORKERS;` would do the trick, or you know, upgrade your module. It's not like it requires special permissions or anything,.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you. Unfortunately I cant upgrade since the system I'm testing on isn't mine. But the 3.01 solution works perfectly on my laptop.

Comment: @friedo Thank you for the documentation link. I'll see if I can convince the owner to upgrade :)