# How to hash a filename down to a small number or digit for output processing

Tags: perl

I am not a Perl programmer but I've inherited existing code that is going to a directory, finding all files iren that folder and subfolder (usually JPG or Office files) and then converting this into a single file to use to load into a SQL Server database. The customer has about 500,000 of these files.

It takes about 45 mins to create the file and then another 45 mins for SQL to load the data. Crudely, it's doing about 150 per second which is reasonable but time is the issue for the job. There are many reasons I don't want to use other techniques so please don't suggest other options unless closely aligned to this process.

What I was considering is to improve speed by running something like 10 processes concurrent. Each process would get passed another argument (0-9). Each process would go to the directory and find all files as it is currently doing but for each file found, it would hash or kludge the filename down to a single digit (0-9) and if that matched the supplied argument, the process would process that file and write it out to it's unique file stream.

Then I would have 10 output files at the end. I doubt that the SQL Server side could be improved as I would have to load to separate tables and then merge in the database and as these are BLOB objects, will not be fast.

So I am looking for some basic code or clues on what functions to use in Perl to take a variable (the file name $File) and generate a single 0 to 9 value based on that. It is probably done by getting the ascii value of each char, then adding these together to get a long number, then add these individual numbers together and eventually you'll get an answer.

Any clues or suggested techniques?

Comment: That assumes every file takes the same amount of time to process. Why not use a [work queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17636255/589924)?

Comment: Your correct in that it is an assumption that all will run around same amount of time. Your threading solution looks good but if it was in some other language, it's over my skill level to try to implement for Perl. It is taking 75 minutes (I incorrectly said 45) so in theory, if total processing comes down to 10 then it's a big win. Thanks.

Comment: While the link I suggested uses threads, that's a specific implementation of my suggestion and by no means the only option. That said, you could use the code from the answer to the question I linked as-is! (Well, change `NUM_WORKERS` to `10`. The file names are supplied for processing via `$q->enqueue`. You can pass them all to a single call of `$q->enqueue` as shown, you can pass them one at a time over multiple calls to `$q->enqueue`, or you can use something in between.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy one to implement suggested in the [`unpack` function documentation](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#unpack):

```
sub string_to_code {
    # convert an arbitrary string to a digit from 0-9
    my ($string) = @_;
    return unpack("%32W*",$string) % 10;
}
```